# IntelliJ and Groovy test source disappearing

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I've recently upgraded to IntelliJ 11 and use it for writing both Java and Groovy.

When I adjust the Project Structure to include src/test/groovy as a Test Source, the setting takes initially.

After a short while, the setting is reverted and src/test/groovy displays as a normal file structure.

Searching around, in Settings > File Associations, *.groovy is indicated as a valid source file.

I've been using IntelliJ for a while, but I'm stumped on this one.
Thanks!

Comment: Is that a Maven project? If so, all the additional source and test source folders should be defined in the pom file, otherwise your manual changes will be reset after Maven project re-import. As a workaround you can disable re-import in Settings | Maven.

Comment: When looking under Project Structure, I noticed a few errors related to the structure (missing dependency), I resolved those and the setting of src/test/groovy as a test source directory appears to hold.  The project validated under Maven from the command-line and when running Maven from inside IntelliJ, so some previous structure defined in the IDEA files must of been hanging around.

Comment: Yes its a Maven project.  I'm using GMaven 1.3 which adds src/test/groovy as a test source on its own (I've never had to explicitly add it as a test source in the POM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The answer for me turned out to be to correct any Project Structure appears reported by IntelliJ as mentioned above.</strike>

At some time I realized this problem would occur every time I changed a POM.  To resolve it (at least for now...), under Settings > Maven > Importing, I checked "Keep source and test folder on reimport", and the situation appears to have resolved itself.

Comment: After a little more time, it appears that fixing all project structure errors does not alleviate the problem, as I still have to re-add src/test/groovy from time to time.  It could be that src/test/groovy is being removed because a parent POM is excluding it, I will look into this more.